# Wordpress Error establishing a database connection in Linux server

Tags: php, mysql, linux, wordpress

Hi i have a problem with the Wordpress admin panel. I have istalled mysql and phpMyAdmin on my Linux server. Then i have uploaded my Wordpress file to server using FileZila. After i installed my wordpress in the Linux server i ran the theme and customize the page using admin dashboard, the phpAdmin page showing when i tried to login "Cannot log in to the MySQL server". 
After that nothing is working in my page. And in my page first time it show following error.[image]

and after that it showing always following error[image]

i don't know what is happening. Please help me to find the error.

Answer (score 1):

can you check your wp-config.php file? see if got correct info. should be something like this.

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'wp');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Comment: There is no problem. It was not changed. Even i can't open trough the phpadmin panel. that.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to */var/log/php-fpm* and checking error.log file  .
In my case, I ran:

> /etc/init.d/mysqld

status with message : mysqld dead but subsys locked

Turned out that mysql was stopped! How that happened remains a mystery since I did not change anything. The solution was to simply run:

> /etc/init.d/mysqld start